# VS code - Python 2.7 - cannot import matplotlib "import-im6.q16: not authorized `mpl' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037."

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have recently started using vs code for a project I am working on, with many difficulties.

I have managed to install the matplotlib package (after a little struggle) and now i am unable to import that package itself. I have posted my code below.

I have tried to look for a solution online

Kind regards,

Connor

```
import matplotlib

import-im6.q16: not authorized `matplotlib' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.
```

Comment: *I have managed to install the matplotlib package* how did you install matplotlib? i have a feeling this is a botched environment

Comment: I got this error verbatim because i ran `import matplotlib` in a *bash* terminal instead of in *python* terminal. Check what language VS code is executing your code in. (should this be an answer?)